# Extract channel/user from YouTube URL with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have these URL's:

```
$url1 = 'https://www.youtube.com/user/funradio/about?disable_polymer=1';
$url2 = 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCM3A_8gPv_TbaMZQZxsvT3A/about';
$url3 = 'channel/UCM3A_8gPv_TbaMZQZxsvT3A/about';
```

I want to extract:

```
user/funradio
channel/UCM3A_8gPv_TbaMZQZxsvT3A
channel/UCM3A_8gPv_TbaMZQZxsvT3A
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: Could you post your code through edit this question?

Answer (score 0):

This will match all 3 strings

```
/user/(.*?)/|(channel/.*?)/
```

Comment: Thanks Dustin, I made some changes you can check it from here: https://regex101.com/r/uD4tK6/6
I can't get correctly the last two URL's, what do you think?